# Very, very sensitive (but possibly very inaccurate) method of detecting voltage differences

Tags: testing, test-equipment, voltmeter

I have a test setup where I need to be able to tell if there is a voltage differential between 2 nodes, but not affect the circuit at all. Some would suggest to using the voltmeter function in a multimeter (as it's voltmeter also has very, very high impedance), but I think the resolution is not there still. I need the resolutions of microvolts. More like, a microvoltmeter is needed.

Now, even as I ask for this, it doesn't mean I want an expensive, high class microvoltmeter. I don't need for the setup to be accurate by the numbers nor have impressively little offset. I just need an indication in resolution of microvolts that there is difference, while having very small effect on the circuit.

Comment: Suppose you make one yourself, how in the world would you check it?  You would need a very good voltmeter.

Comment: What you describe is the essence of an operational amplifier. Most will have too high gain though and will saturate. So an instrumentation amp is more feasible.

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen: The good old chicken & egg problem.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What are the magnitudes of the voltages at your 2 nodes? Are you trying to detect differences of microvolts for volt level signals or for millivolt level signals? A good 6-1/2 digit voltmeter could do either, though. Are your signals stable enough for this comparison to be meaningful? If you described your application in more detail, we might be able to offer a better solution.

Comment: if it is not low offset it will see a difference when there is none.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on the exact circuit and requirements, an instrumentation amplifier can do the job. If you have high common mode voltage, a voltmeter might be your only choice.

Comment: You use the terms in-amp and voltmeter as if they were mutually exclusive. Can you elaborate on the purported quality of a "voltmeter", that an "in-amp" doesn't have?

Comment: Means I don't have to waste any more time putting together an in-amp, if quick & dirty would do.

Comment: I asked to detect differences, that means a comparator would also do. Why be fixated with in-amps?

Comment: There are ready made instrumentation amplifiers, where the only passives are 1 gain resistor and decoupling capacitors. Easy. Voltmeter will have an instrumentation amplifier along with gain control and input protection - easier, but more expensive.